# Mock HTTP response in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have an application that internally talks http with an resource server. I would like to be able to test this application using robot but without mocking anything in the actual code, meaning I would like robot to sniff and capture any http request from the app and then respond using a preset response. I cannot find any such, all I can find is http libraries that allow robot to do the requests

Comment: Perhaps someone more experienced than me can give you an answer you want to hear but I'm afraid it sounds like you need to build a dummy web service or mock to throw back these expected responses.

Comment: Yup, thats one way to do it, the problem with that approach is that all the URL in the app must be from env variables so you can change all to localhost:<port> to redirect to your test server. You would not be able to expect/differentiate the requests "www.google.com/picts" and "www.yahoo.com/picts", both would come as localhost/picts. That is fine in my usecase and probably the route I will take, but hopefully the lib is already written :D

Comment: Mockpy is a Python module that seems to do what you need: https://github.com/oarrabi/mockpy

Comment: @Pekka, sure does, and with proxy == no need for env variables! Sweet! Then it's just to wrap/create a nice robot lib for this.

Comment: https://github.com/robotframework/Rammbock/wiki/RammbockUserGuide